# How to create date index for time serie

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to read this data as a time serie, but python doesn't recognize the colomns name. Here is my code

```
 speedmat= pandas.read_pickle('../data/simulation_simple/speed_matrix_2015')
 timeserie= speedmat.T.iloc[:, 0:8064]
 timeserietimeserie["stamp"]=pd.to_datetime(timeserie["stamp"])
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'stamp'
```

thank you for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXbFJ.png)

I tried to code timeserietimeserie["stamp"]=pd.to_datetime(timeserie["stamp"]) but did nt work

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

need miniaml and reproducible example for answer. let's make!

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02'])
```

`df`

```
    2022-01-01  2022-01-02
0   1           2
```

**Code**

try this

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

`df`

```
    2022-01-01  2022-01-02
0   1           2
```

chk datetime or not.

```
print(df.columns)
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

DatetimeIndex

Comment: Thank you Kim. Here what I got after trying your code. It seems that he does not recognize the columns name                                                                                       
               DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:05:00',
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='stamp', length=8064, freq=None)              
the error   KeyError: "None of ['stamp'] are in the columns"